RuntimeError: Cannot determine SoC peripheral base address with RPi.GPIO on Raspberry Pi
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

PWM_GPIO = 27
SPEED_GPIO = 22

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PWM_GPIO, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(SPEED_GPIO, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

I’ve double-checked that:

The RPi.GPIO library is installed correctly.

The Raspberry Pi is powered on and connected properly.

The purpose of the code is to read input pulses on specific GPIO pins for my project.


I also tried restarting the Raspberry Pi and updating the OS, but the issue persists. Is there something I’m missing, or is there an alternative way to configure GPIO inputs that avoids this error?

I'm using Raspberrypi 5 Model B

I recommend to avoid using that library and use what Linux kernel provides for you (perhaps with a help of libgpiod).
